# Java consecutive checker

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code which checks if a string or either letters or numbers is consecutive, however every time I run the program it gives me nothing back but an error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`.

Im not sure what the problem is as I am fairly new to programming, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Question1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    java.util.Scanner keyboardReader = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = keyboardReader.nextLine();
    isConsecutive(userInput);
  }
  public static void isConsecutive(String s)
  {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int x = 0;
    char [] inputArray = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
      if (Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[(i+1)]) != 1)
      {       
        System.out.println("false");
      }
      else
      {
        x++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to do:

```
for (int i=0; i < s.length() - 1; i++)
```

because when the loop is at the last execution step and calculates

`Math.abs(inputArray[i] - inputArray[(i+1)]) != 1`,

then `inputArray[i+1]` refers to an element which is out of the array bounds.